# Can't get list item ID with jQuery

Tags: html, ajax

I need to pass list element ID to ajax, and this code doesn't seem to do the job:

HTML:

```
    <ul  id="tree">
       <li><a id="1">Finance</a></li>
       <li><a id="2">ACC</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url()?>admincont/departament/6>">HR</a></li>
   </ul>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('#tree li').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
       method: "POST",
       data: {depID: $(this).attr('id')},// i have also tried  $(this).id
      url: "<?php echo base_url();?>/assets/getdepartment.php",
      success: function(msg){
        $('#result').html(msg);
      }
    })
  })
});
</script>
```

My php file:

```
<?php
$depID = $_POST['depID'];
echo $depID;
?>
```

In my result div, i get 
"Notice: Undefined index: depID in line 2"

Answer (score 5):

`this` doesn't refer to your anchor, it refers to the list item.

You can find the anchor using `this` though:

```
data: {depID: $(this).find('a').attr('id')}
```

Or (preferable, in my opinion), simply attach the event handler to the anchor instead:

```
$('#tree li a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // If you need to prevent the default behaviour
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        data: {depID: $(this).attr('id')},
        url: "<?php echo base_url();?>/assets/getdepartment.php",
        success: function(msg){
            $('#result').html(msg);
       }
   })
})
```